# jQuery HTML select binded to click works only once

Tags: jquery, html

I have the code given below.I was trying to make it work using the jQuery's `.on` function. But it doesn't seem to work. What I'm trying to do basically is to press onclick on the desired element, each time I select an option on a HTML select. It only works the first time

```
$('#orderby').on('change',function() {
    var orderbyOption = $('#orderby option:selected').val()

    if (orderbyOption == "proyecto"){
        $('#proyectoOrder').click();
    }

    if (orderbyOption == "ano"){
        $('#anoOrder').click();
    }

    if (orderbyOption == "tipo"){
        $('#tipoOrder').click();
    }
});
```

where `orderby` is the `id` of the `select` element

```
<select id="orderby" style="float: left; left: 360px; padding-top: 2px; position: absolute; text-align: left; top: 6px;">
    <option value="projecto">projecto</option>
    <option value="ano">ano</option>
    <option value="tipo">tipo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The selected option is simply `$('#orderby').val()`

Comment: Change the first line to `var orderbyOption = $(this).val()`

Comment: It works for me... the click is always triggered, but only if you change the actually selected option... this is correct because this is the way the change event works...

Comment: there is a typo. u have typed in proyecto instead of projecto

Answer (score 2):

Code can be simplified to :

```
$('#orderby').on('change', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).val() + 'Order').click();
});
```

If you still have the same problem, then it is likely that one or more of the click actions affects/replaces the select element or its change handler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can simplify the code:

```
$('#orderby').on('change',function() {
    var orderbyOption = $(this).val()
    $('#'+orderbyOption+'Order').trigger('click');
    console.log('#'+orderbyOption+'Order'); // To check the id
});​
```

You can try a working solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/uy4rx/